# Django and android

Tags: android, django

I have to build a python based (server based) HR system with the following features:

Possibility to add/edit/remove employees by an admin .

Possibility of employees to mark their check in/ check out time.

Possibility to mark days on which they will be on leave .

Also , I have to build a mobile app which integrates to the above system and allows employees to mark attendance from the application.

Any suggestions on how to do it ? Please Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to use django-tastypie for building rest-api between your web and mobile apps

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/